# App crashes when overriding the views height-constraint to zero

Tags: ios, swift, layout, autolayout, constraints

In my app I have three `UIViews` with a `UILabel`and a `UITableView` in it displaying users. When there are no users I want to hide the view completely. Currently I'm trying to set the views heightAnchor to zero but this results in this error:

> Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
>
> "NSLayoutConstraint:0x604000286cc0 LebensfitFirebase.SurePeople:0x7ff0305d5d30.height == 300   (active)>",
>
> "NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c000095b30 
>   LebensfitFirebase.SurePeople:0x7ff0305d5d30.height == 0   (active)>"
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
>
> NSLayoutConstraint:0x604000286cc0 LebensfitFirebase.SurePeople:0x7ff0305d5d30.height == 300   (active)>

What do I have to concern to make this work? Btw, I have set the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`to false.
First I set the three views like this:

```
surePeopleTV.anchor(top: descLabel.bottomAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
maybePeopleTV.anchor(top: surePeopleTV.bottomAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
nopePeopleTV.anchor(top: maybePeopleTV.bottomAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
```

This is a custom method for setting the constraints in one line. The height constant does not get set to 0 with this method.

Then later in my program I care about the height constraint when the users in the tableviews are updated:

```
func teilnehmerLoaded() {
    if surePeopleTV.finishedLoading == true && maybePeopleTV.finishedLoading == true && nopePeopleTV.finishedLoading == true {
        view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
        for controller in tableViewControllers {
            if controller.users.count > 0 {
                let height: CGFloat = 300
                controller.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: height).isActive = true
                controller.confBounds()
            } else {
                controller.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0).isActive = true 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This creates constraints every call of function and causes conflicts instead you want

```
var heightCon:NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Inside `viewDidLoad`

```
heightCon =  controller.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: <#defaultHeight#>)
heightCon.isActive = true
```

Then play with constant value

```
func teilnehmerLoaded() {
    if surePeopleTV.finishedLoading == true && maybePeopleTV.finishedLoading == true && nopePeopleTV.finishedLoading == true {
        view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
        for controller in tableViewControllers {
            if controller.users.count > 0 {
                heightCon.constant = 300
                view.layoutIfNeeded()
                controller.confBounds()
            } else {
                heightCon.constant = 0
                view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

BTW : if you have array case then use

```
var heightCons = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
```

then append created constraints and access them from array by your for loop in    `teilnehmerLoaded`

---

Another best way is

```
func teilnehmerLoaded() {
    if surePeopleTV.finishedLoading == true && maybePeopleTV.finishedLoading == true && nopePeopleTV.finishedLoading == true {
         for controller in tableViewControllers {
            if let heightCon = controller.constraints.first { $0.identifier == "height" }  {

                  heightCon.constant = controller.users.count > 0 ? 300 : 0
            }
            else {

                  let heightCon = controller.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:  controller.users.count > 0 ? 300 : 0)
                  heightCon.isActive = true
                  heightCon.identifier = "height"
             }

             if controller.users.count > 0 {
                controller.confBounds()
             }

        }

        view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Sh_Khan I was able to solve it:

```
var heightCons = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
```

Inside `ViewDidLoad`:

```
for controller in tableViewControllers {
        let heightCon = controller.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0)
        heightCon.isActive = true
        heightCons.append(heightCon)
}
```

And the function looks like this now:

```
func teilnehmerLoaded() {
    if surePeopleTV.finishedLoading == true && maybePeopleTV.finishedLoading == true && nopePeopleTV.finishedLoading == true {
        for (index, controller) in tableViewControllers.enumerated() {
            var height = CGFloat(controller.users.count) * 60.0
            if controller.users.count > 0 {
                height += (25 + 20)
                heightCons[index].constant = height
                controller.confBounds()
            } else {
                heightCons[index].constant = height
            }
            view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}
```